# Get all available promotions for specific commerce product

Tags: 8, commerce

How to get all available promotions, which apply to specific product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via `commerce_order.price_calculator` service:

```
$context = new Context($this->currentUser, $this->currentStore->getStore(), NULL, [
    'field_name' => $items->getName(),
]);
/** @var \Drupal\commerce\PurchasableEntityInterface $purchasable_entity */
$purchasable_entity = $items->getEntity();
$adjustment_types = array_filter($this->getSetting('adjustment_types'));
$result = $this->priceCalculator->calculate($purchasable_entity, 1, $context, $adjustment_types);

//Get promotions
$promos = $result->getAdjustments();
```